# Bloons TD Battles

Tags: bloons-td-battles

I play Bloons TD Battles and I love it the only problem is how do I get more medallions? I play I have a status of 11/10 wins and loses is there a way I can get better?

Answer (score 1):

You get medallions for winning; the more battles you play, the more games you'll win, and so the more medallions you'll get. You **only** get medallions for winning though, any losses don't help you at all.